# Update query suddenly stopped working after migration on Unix server

Tags: mysql

a program that worked until a few days ago today gave back the following error in Production environment :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntaz to use near', owner='user@domain', check_datetime=NOW(), WHERE id = 26922 at line 1.

the complete query is :

```
**UPDATE anomalie_ordini.taa_tb_overview_rapporti
SET status_rapporto_id= <val_num>, owner='<val_char>', check_datetime=NOW()
WHERE id=<val_num>**
```

the same query run in Development environment without problems.

Could be tied to a migration of the server where the query runs?

Hope you can help me.
Thank you.

EDIT: find the error, one of the columns were named ROWS, a reserved word (not my choice :) )

Comment: The error you're getting most likely comes from the value you use in `<val_num>`. Hopefully it's not a non-sanitized user input :)

Comment: `val_num` is merged in again in the `where` and its value looks fine, so it doesn't look like it has an invalid value, but it depends on how you are substituting the template values for the real values - looks like the first one isn't getting substituted - posting some of the actual original code might help.